# Suing an Airline Over lost luggage

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, contract-law, air-travel

I have been back and forth with this Arline company that lost my luggage back in 2015. They keep forwarding me to different people and asking for the same information over and over and never pay me. What should I do? Is it worth suing them?
Flight from SFO to EWR

Comment: Airlines are limited in liability for lost luggage by the Montreal Convention, so it depends on what you sue for and how cheaply you can do it.

Comment: @moo the Montreal convention only applies to international flights - the OP hasn’t indicated that’s the case

Comment: Beware of possible statute of limitations.

Comment: You might want to provide more details. Was this an international flight (see previous comments)? Also the state might be relevant. What do airline agents/employees tell you once you give them the information? Do the Terms & Conditions (or similar document) specify the applicable law or jurisdiction in case of controversy?

Answer (score 1):

Speak to a lawyer.

Many legal firms do free consultations. This way you can find out if there is a chance of success and what your next steps are.